# TypeError when passing 2d numpy array to C++

Tags: arrays, numpy, swig

I have two-dimensional data in a numpyarray and C++-code that I want to perform some action on this data. Using swig and distutils and the `numpy.i` I managed to compile everything into a python extension "goldstein", that provides a function `unwrap2d`.
I test it using

```
import goldstein

data = np.ascontiguousarray(data_temp, dtype='double')
mask = np.ascontiguousarray(mask_temp, dtype='uint16')
outdata = np.ones_like(data)

goldstein.unwrap2d(data,mask,outdata)
```

I get a `TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type`. Can anyone point me towards how I can pass these arrays in the right way?

For reference: For creating the module I used the interface-file

```
%define DOCSTRING
"Wrapper for c++-code"
%enddef

%module(docstring=DOCSTRING) goldstein

%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "goldstein.h"
%}

/*include numpy typemaps*/
%include "numpy.i"
/*initialize module*/
%init %{
    import_array();
%}

%rename(unwrap2d) phase_unwrapping_func;

/* typemaps for the arrays*/
%apply (int DIM1,int DIM2,float* IN_ARRAY2) {(int xsize,int ysize,float* in)};
%apply (int DIM1,int DIM2,unsigned short* IN_ARRAY2) {(int x1,int y1,unsigned short* mask)};
%apply (int DIM1,int DIM2,float* INPLACE_ARRAY2) {(int x2,int y2,float* out)};

/*wrapper function calling the original phase_unwrapping using only the needed parameters*/
%inline %{
void phase_unwrapping_func(int xsize,int ysize,float* in,int x1,int y1,unsigned short* mask,int x2,int y2,float* out) {
    phase_unwrapping(xsize, ysize, in, mask, out);
    }
%}
```

Comment: I tried to turn on syntax-highlighting, but i did not succeed... :(

Comment: Your `data` array is of dtype double, but your C function is expecting a float. That's probably what's making NumPy complain. Doing `data = np.ascontiguousarray(data_temp, dtype='float')` before calling your function should take care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jaimie is right of course. 'float' like 'double' is 64-bit in numpy, thats why I didnt check again, I just remembered it does not matter. But float in c++ obviously needs 32-bit, which in numpy is `'float32'`.
Thank you!